# Android 14 API 34. No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: java, android-14, android-api-34

I had a working code. **It is working fine till Android 13 but from Android 14 it is not working**.

Problem:
application needs to start a new activity-for-result. On launching new Activity, code is throwing exception.

Code:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> myNewActivity = myActivity.registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    , result -> myActivityResult(getJotterReqNo(), result.getResultCode(), result.getData())
);

myNewActivity.launch(new Intent(getMyActivity().ACTIVITY_TO_LAUNCH));
```

Exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=app.my.application.MyActivity }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2239)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1878)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5589)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:780)
at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat$Api16Impl.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:854)
at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:245)
at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$1.onLaunch(ComponentActivity.java:239)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$2.launch(ActivityResultRegistry.java:173)
at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher.launch(ActivityResultLauncher.java:47)
at app.my.application.fragments.applicationsList.MainActivity.onListItemClicked(MainActivity.java:241)
at app.my.application.fragments.applicationsList.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.onItemClick(Unknown Source:6)
```

Comment: Looks like there was a [security change for intents](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#security) ... maybe that info can help? Unfortunately, I do not know enough Android development to assist.

Comment: Good news! ... as you can accept your own answer, consider posting an answer for what had to change for your particular situation to get working. The information may help others that cross the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As [Paul T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7644018/paul-t) mentioned, there has been a security change in Android that restricts implicit intents for apps targeting Android 14+.

> - Implicit intents are only delivered to exported components. Apps must either use an explicit intent to deliver to unexported    components, or mark the component as exported.
> - If an app creates a    mutable pending intent with an intent that doesn't specify a    component or package, the system now throws an
>   exception.
>
> These changes prevent malicious apps from intercepting implicit
> intents that are intended for use by an app's internal components.

Option 1 :

```
<activity
    android:name=".AppActivity"
    android:exported="true">
```

Option 2 :

```
<activity
android:name=".AppActivity"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.action.APP_ACTION" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

```
// This makes the intent explicit.
Intent explicitIntent =
        new Intent("com.example.action.APP_ACTION")
explicitIntent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
context.startActivity(explicitIntent);
```

You can read more here,

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-14#security